# Integrate a public but non static member function with ALGLIB

Tags: c++, pointers, integral, alglib

I am trying to integrate a member function of a class, and needs some help! I cannot declare the function static because this function uses non-static private members (more specifically use a private member which is another class). **I am using C++17 and cannot downgrade**

I write below a Minimum (Non) Working Example that mimic my problem. The aim is to find what to put instead of the four question marks '????' in `alglib::autogkintegrate(s, ????, params)`.

The `alglib::autogkintegrate` function takes three arguments:

1. a 'state' which contains the current value of the integration, integral boundaries, other stuff?)
2. The function `f` to integrate which **must be** of the prototype `void f(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, double &y, void *ptr)`
3. an optional pointer `void *ptr` which contains extra parameters for the function `f`

Here is the non working example:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include "integration.h"

class Foo;
class Bar;

/*****************************
    Class Foo
*****************************/
class Foo
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        Foo(Bar *b, int toto);

        // Function to integrate
        void f(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, double &y, void *ptr);
        
    private:
        Bar *m_bar;
        int m_toto;
};

Foo::Foo(Bar *b, int toto) : m_bar(b), m_toto(toto)
{}

void Foo::f(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, double &y, void *ptr)
{
    double *param = (double *) ptr;
    double p1 = param[0];
    double p2 = param[1];

    y = exp(this->m_toto*x)/(p1 * p2);
}

/*****************************
    Class Bar
*****************************/
class Bar
{
    friend Foo;
    public:
        // Constructor
        Bar();
        
    private:
        int m_a, m_b;
};

Bar::Bar() : m_a(2), m_b(5)
{}

/*****************************
    Main program
*****************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Bar* b = new Bar();

    Foo f(b, 87);

    double arrayParams[2] = {1, 2};
    double (*params)[2] = &arrayParams;

    alglib::autogkstate s;
    double v;
    alglib::autogkreport rep;
    alglib::autogksmooth(0, 1, s);
    alglib::autogkintegrate(s, ????, params);
    alglib::autogkresults(s, v, rep);

    return 0;
}
```

If I declare the function `f` as static (and remove `this->m_toto`in `f`), then I can integrate `f`by using `alglib::autogkintegrate(s, Foo::f, params);`. So the problem is really to get access to the function `f`.

I tried to define a pointer to member function (which explains `#include <functional>`) but failed to use it in `alglib::autogkintegrate(s, ????, params);`

**To repeat my question: I want to integrate a member function of a class using ``Alglib``` in C++**

Useful links:

1. https://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#gs_using section 8.5
2. https://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#example_autogk_d1

P.S.: I also posted this question at http://forum.alglib.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4352 which is a dedicated forum to Alglib (but looks much less active than Stack Overflow, hence my double post. If I get an answer there, I will copy-paste here, and vice-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html using a global variable (sorry...). I post here the code adapted to my question if anyone needs it:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include "integration.h"

class Foo;
class Bar;

void* pt2Object; // global variable which points to an arbitrary object

/*****************************
    Class Foo
*****************************/
class Foo
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        Foo(Bar *b, int toto);

        // Function to integrate
        void f(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, double &y, void *ptr);

        // Wrapper
        static void Wrapper_To_Call_f(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, double &y, void *ptr);
        
    private:
        Bar *m_bar;
        int m_toto;
};

Foo::Foo(Bar *b, int toto) : m_bar(b), m_toto(toto)
{}

void Foo::f(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, double &y, void *ptr)
{
    double *param = (double *) ptr;
    double p1 = param[0];
    double p2 = param[1];

    y = exp(this->m_toto*x)/(p1 * p2);
    // y = exp(x)/(p1 * p2);
}

void Foo::Wrapper_To_Call_f(double x, double xminusa, double bminusx, double &y, void *ptr)
{
    // explicitly cast global variable <pt2Object> to a pointer to TClassB
    // warning: <pt2Object> MUST point to an appropriate object!
    Foo* mySelf = (Foo*) pt2Object;

    // call member
    mySelf->f(x, xminusa, bminusx, y, ptr);
}

/*****************************
    Class Bar
*****************************/
class Bar
{
    friend Foo;
    public:
        // Constructor
        Bar();
        
    private:
        int m_a, m_b;
};

Bar::Bar() : m_a(2), m_b(5)
{}

/*****************************
    Main program
*****************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Bar* b = new Bar();

    // Create Foo
    Foo myFoo(b, 1);
    // Assign global variable which is used in the static wrapper function
    // important: never forget to do this!!
    pt2Object = (void*) &myFoo;

    double arrayParams[2] = {1, 2};
    double (*params)[2] = &arrayParams;

    alglib::autogkstate s;
    double v;
    alglib::autogkreport rep;
    alglib::autogksmooth(0, 1, s);
    alglib::autogkintegrate(s, Foo::Wrapper_To_Call_f, params);
    alglib::autogkresults(s, v, rep);

    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```